# Differentiation Properties Question

Tags: derivatives

[image]So I am running into this question, and I am not sure if desmos is wrong in this case.

The question is true or false:

> If f · g and g is differentiable at x = a, then f is differentiable at
>   x = a.

A counter example would be:
g(x) = 0
f(x) = |x|
So f(x)*g(x) = 0.

Therefore g'(x) = 0, f'(x) = undefined, (f*g)'(x) = 0

But according to desmos this doesn't work and the derivative of f*g is undefined, I am looking for insight about whether this statement is true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such statement is false in general. Just consider $f(x) = x^{-1}$, $g(x) = x$ and $a = 0$.

Comment: Any idea why according to desmos this example does not work?

Comment: Maybe it is because $f$ is not defined at $0$, so the given software does not recognize $h(x)$ as a function defined over the reals.